# Cleanup: best way to remove WooCommerce comments from the wp_comments table

Tags: database, woocommerce-offtopic, optimization

I am optimizing the database of my site that is using [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/).

When I came across the `wp_comments` table, I found it close to 100 MB in total. It's all filled with WooCommerce order statuses from last few years.

What's the best way to decrease the size of my database?

Comment: if you don't need the order status, you can remove row if older than X date

Comment: Are you sure that the data is stored in the `wp_comments` table? I see there is a `wp_woocommerce_order_items` and `wp_woocommerce_order_itemsmeta` table that may be related.

Comment: @bynicolas there are lots of rows as i told its close to 100mb

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan I think Woocommerce does use the comments table to store order statuses

Comment: Hm, I see. @H.Ahuja did you already try removing all of your order status from the last few years through the WordPress Dashboard?

Comment: @H.Ahuja My comment was more of a confirmation. Do you need those old statuses? if not, you can delete rows that have dates older than a specified time by using an SQL statement

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan how can they be removed from dashboard?i am not sure

Comment: @H.Ahuja well you'd have to delete the related post to remove from dashboard. if you only want to remove order statuses (comments) you'd need to use SQL. This can be done through PHPMyAdmin for instance

Comment: @H.Ahuja Please share me a screenshot of some of the rows you see with the order statuses in your `wp_comments` table. I'll need to see the prefix that is being used.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan which prefix you want to see?

Comment: @H.Ahuja Has this question been resolved? To answer your last question. May you update you question with some of the rows in your database that you want to remove?

Answer (score 0):

To delete rows in your `wp_comments` you can use an SQL statement like so

```
DELETE FROM wp_comments where comment_date < '2016-01-01' and comment_type = 'order_notes'
```

This will delete all comments older than January 1st 2016.  I do believe Woocommerce uses `order_notes` as a `comment_type` make sure by checking that column before running the statement.

Of course, you need to adapt the `FROM wp_comments` to reflect the prefix you are using in your DB.

Also make a backup of your DB **BEFORE** running this statement, it will **ERASE** your data!

**EDIT**

here's an alternative statement

```
DELETE FROM wp_comments where comment_date < DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL -365 DAY) and comment_type = 'order_notes'
```

It does the same job but the SQL statement will generate the today date and remove 365 days from it and delete everything older than 365 days.  I find it easier to work with. You could run this statement every month and it will always remove entries older than 365 days from run time.

Comment: Thanks for these but i am afraid of using these,as data in comments table is linked to other tables like commentmeta .Do you know where order status notes in comments table are eventually used?

Comment: well you asked how to shrink the size of `wp_comments`, this is how. Now you indeed would need to make an additional check by querying the `wp_comments` before and retrieving IDs of the rows you are about to delete.  Then remove corresponding rows in `wp_commentmeta` if you wish to keep this clean also. As of to where order status notes are used... I don't know.  I would assume that they used it only in the order post to display relevant info but I would recommend to check with Woocommerce forums to make sure of that.

Comment: your concern is valid, a better way is to use a wp cli command - see https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/comment/ or a custom command using `wp_delete_comment`